# Re-use a WebGL context between mounted/unmounted components

Tags: html, reactjs, canvas, webgl, webgl2

I have two components with a `<canvas />` and I want to use the same WebGL context that doesn't go away after these components are unmounted.

One component is `<GameCanvas />` and the other is `<PlayerCanvas />`. Either one is mounted or the other and I want to use the same context from `canvas.getContext("webgl2")` once one of those is unmounted and then mounted again.

Can this be done with some kind of detached WebGL context?

Comment: I would use a portal and never actually remove the canvas from the dom

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a WebGL context is attached to one and only one canvas.
If you have two distinct canvases, you will need to create two WebGLRenderingContext instances.

```
function MyComp() {
  const handleMount = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => {
    if (!canvas) return

    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl")
    ...
  }
  return <canvas ref={handleMount}></canvas>
}
```